# VBA to get the date of the Previous Workday

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the Previous working day of today. Say if suppose today is Wednesday, then the previous working day will be Tueday but if today is Monday then the previous working day will be Friday. How do I get the date of the previous working day?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)
```

[image]

This formula can be easily modified to handle holidays.

In VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox CDate(Evaluate("WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Why Evaluate and not `WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to say that this function can handle also Public Holidays, but this argument is optional. So in fact we have:

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1, 'Range with Public Holidays Dates')
```

for example:

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1, A1:A10)
```