# How to determine the workday prior to ReceivedTime?

Tags: vba, date, outlook

The following code saves Outlook attachments and adds the date that the email was generated to the end of the name.

I am trying to add the previous workday.

```vb
Public Sub K_P3(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "W:XXXX\"

    Dim dateformat As String
    dateformat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & _
          Left(objAtt.FileName, InStrRev(objAtt.FileName, ".") - 1) & _
          " " & dateformat & _
          Mid(objAtt.FileName, InStrRev(objAtt.FileName, "."))
        
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Date-time is stored numerically so you can subtract 1 - `Format(itm.ReceivedTime-1, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")`

Comment: Is there something I can use other than itm.receviedtime so that it only displays workdays?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898970/vba-to-get-the-date-of-the-previous-workday

Comment: Having trouble incorporating this into the code i posted

Comment: So you want the same time as `itm.ReceivedTime` but adjusted to the previous workday?

Comment: Yep, so if the itm.receivedtime was on a Monday it would show the previous Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    dateformat = Format(application.workday(itm.ReceivedTime),-1), "yyyy-mm-dd") & _
                 Format(itm.ReceivedTime, " Hmm")
```

EDIT: forgot you were using Outlook:

```vb
dateformat = Format(Workday(itm.ReceivedTime,1), "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm")
```

Some code to (I think) mimic Excel's workday function:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim arrHolidays
    arrHolidays = Array(#12/25/2019#) 'array of holidays
    
    Debug.Print Workday(#12/26/2019#, -1)              '12/25/2019
    Debug.Print Workday(#12/26/2019#, -1, arrHolidays) '12/24/2019
End Sub

'Find the workday `days` ago or in the future starting from `dt`.
'Ignores weekends, and optionally also an array of dates passed to `arrHols`
Function Workday(dt As Date, ByVal days, Optional arrHols As Variant = Empty)
    Dim rv, i, dy, delta, hol As Boolean
    rv = dt
    i = 0
    delta = IIf(days < 0, -1, 1) 'what direction are we headed?
    Do While i <> days
        rv = rv + delta
        dy = Weekday(rv, vbMonday)         'Monday=1
        If dy <> 6 And dy <> 7 Then        'not a weekend?
            'Int() below removes any time component from the date
            If Not IsEmpty(arrHols) Then hol = InArray(Int(rv), arrHols)
            If Not hol Then i = i + delta  'not a holiday?
        End If
    Loop
    Workday = rv
End Function

'Is value `v` in the array `arr` ?
Function InArray(ByVal v, arr) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    If IsEmpty(arr) Then Exit Function
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = v Then
            InArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I changed to the following and nothing saves down now. Does the application.workday work in outlook vba?                               
                                                                                                  
 dateformat = Format(Application.workday(itm.ReceivedTime, -1), "yyyy-mm-dd") & _
             Format(itm.ReceivedTime, " Hmm")

Comment: Sorry I forgot you were in Outlook - I spend all my time in Excel...   Would it be OK if it just took into account weekday/weekend, and not (eg) holidays?

Comment: Can't seem to get it to run unfortunately. Do I need to declare any of these variables or anything?

Comment: What does it do *instead* of running?  It's easier for me to make suggestions if you describe exactly what happens.  Do you get an error?

Comment: Error on my part, it worked! Thank you! If I was to set up for holidays I would need to manually define them all correct?

Comment: Could I update the macro so that it opens an excel file where i have this line: WORKDAY(C4,-1,Holidays!$A$2:$A$200) with C4 being todays date. Then it would copy the cell and use that in the name o the attachment I would be saving down? If so do you have an idea about how to implement that?

Comment: I did not realize but by default WorkDay doesn't include holidays (only weekends) unless you pass a list, so even if you called the excel version you'd still need to provide a list of holidays.  Given that, it might be easier to continue with word VBA but have a hard-coded list of days which are holidays.  I can may be take a look later.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you so much hopefully I can get as good at macros as you some day.

Comment: No problem - good to hear it's working for you.