# How to change Date Output from Today's Date to "Last Business Day"

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-2010

```
  'Range("B18").Value = Date`
```

I'm looking for help at the end of my code specifically regarding "Range("B18").Value = Date"

It posts the current date (For example, May 31) when I need it to post "-1 Business Day" (So May 30 instead.) and then if the current date falls on a Monday (May 29), to post Friday's date instead (May 26).

I've been stuck on this for a while. I can see solutions online on how to do it directly within Excel, but can't figure out the VBA equivalent.

Comment: `Range("B18").Value = Application.Workday(Date,-1)`

Comment: Question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898970/vba-to-get-the-date-of-the-previous-workday

Comment: If VBA.Weekday(VBA.Date()) = 2 Then Range("B18").FormulaR1C1 = VBA.Date() - 3

Comment: @ScottCraner that works!!! However it posts it in "General" formatting, if I change it to the Date setting, it looks right, but how do I get it to post it as a date?

Comment: `Range("B18").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"`